# Super generic F# - maybe these are HKTs?

Tags: functional-programming, f#, higher-kinded-types

So, I'm working on a new generic CLI args parser (mostly for my own benefit, we'll see if I come up with something useful worth publishing).

Let's just say to start with that I have a function that has this signature: `(ArgumentConfiguration<'a> -> string array -> 'a * string array` - so in other words, I have a function that will extract out and give me the value of a particular configured argument, and the remaining elements of the string array. The generic type `'a` is unbounded, so it could be `int`, `float`, `Foo`, whatever. There's a `Parse` function in the config type that returns whatever I need.

Ok cool. Next thing is to have a data structure the user can input that contains all of those parsers, and a function that will take that structure and return the same "shape" of structure but instead of `ArgumentConfiguration<'a>` it will just return `'a`. Here's a more concrete example:

```
(* Input Type *)
type ArgumentInput = {
  A: ArgumentConfiguration<float>
  B: ArgumentConfiguration<int>
  C: ArgumentConfiguration<boolean>
}

(* Expected return type that I don't want to specify - I want it inferred *)
type ParserResult = {
  A: float
  B: int
  C: boolean
}
```

The key is this: I want this to be as strongly typed as possible, but obviously I have different types of different arguments all over the place.
I'm open to doing different structures too - perhaps a Map might work? even a Sequence? Collections seem like not the right answer though if I'm going to have a `ArgumentConfiguration<float>` next to an `ArgumentConfiguration<int>` etc.

So given all of this info, here are my questions:

1. What kind of data structure would work well to store these data so that the data and type can be transformed in a function?
2. How would the function signature work?

   - Because I'm familiar with Typescript and the way it does things (though I want this in F#) the signature I imagine would be like `type ParserFn = (config: Record<string, ArgumentConfiguration<any>>) => (args: string[]) => Record<string, any>;` except that nukes the types for each record entry (and I don't think there's a good workaround in Typescript for that either; just using TS since I know it better)

Being enthusiastic about advanced FP concepts but not necessarily the most experienced, I wonder if I've stumbled on a limitation of the F# type system (would a new custom Type Provider help me?), and whether a language like Haskell or even Idris might be required to fully express the logic I'm looking at writing.

Comment: take a look at https://www.gresearch.co.uk/article/squeezing-more-out-of-the-f-type-system-introducing-crates/....it MAY help you, I havent actually read the thing completely, it MAY be you need existential quantification, that you can similate.

Comment: @MrD thanks, but that link got a 404

Comment: I think you can use a tuple instead of a record. Then you can run the function over each element of the tuple to get the a. To do that you'll need a generic function to map over tuple elements, it's tricky but you can define it using static constraints.

Comment: https://www.gresearch.co.uk/article/squeezing-more-out-of-the-f-type-system-introducing-crates/